# difference between "having" and "coming to have" in the mentioned context?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> Their **having/coming to have** X is the result of her intending so.

What is the difference between "having" and "coming to have" in the above sentence.

Answer (score 3):

**come to have** expresses the idea of *process of acquisition*.

> How did you **come to have** the keys to the cafeteria pantry?

How did those keys find their way into your possession? How did you manage to get them?  What series of events transpired that allowed you to get your hands on those keys?  In brief, how did you **acquire** those keys?

Having  = possessing
Coming to have  = acquiring

Answer (score 2):

> Their **having** X is the result of her intending so.

Means they possess *something* right now, where as

> Their **coming to have** X is the result of her intending so.

Is more about what they **needed to do in order to get** *X*.